# Angular2 input data getting lost on button click

Tags: angular, input

I have created Angular2 code like this to get the data on button click

```
    <div class="field-panel">
        <div>
          <span>
             <input #newData [(ngModel)]="data.id" type="text" >
             <select #newCategory [(ngModel)]="i.index" class="input-bars">
              <option *ngFor="let data of field" [value]="data.value">{{data.value}}</option>
            </select>
          </span>
        <button class="btn btn-success (click)="addData(newData.value, newCategory.value)">ADD</button>
         </div>
    </div>

    addData(value, dropValue){

        this.Data[index] = value;
    }
```

But when the button is clicked the data on the input field is getting lost in ui. How to keep it when the button is clicked and display on the ui as well??

Comment: Could you please post your addData and the essentials of your html that the button is contained in?

Comment: @silentsod i'm using the `select` dropdown as well, I have edited the code

Comment: Honestly, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish with your code, but here's a stab with a plunker, you'll note that clicking add doesn't clear any input fields:
https://plnkr.co/edit/xTBSLfnxDvYXGHM4zjFa?p=preview

Comment: I know the reason it's becuase you are using push to store the details to the array and i'm using `this.Data[index] = value;` this to store the data to array

Answer (score 1):

I'll hazard a guess that you're working in a form, so add `type="button"` to the button `<button class="btn btn-success" (click)="addData(newData.value)">ADD</button>`. That should prevent it from thinking the form is submitting and clearing the data.